# How to offset shell layer in abaqus python scripting

Tags: python, abaqus

I need to offset a shell layer from my geometry via python scripting. I have done it using the abaqus interface, but I need to code it [See attached figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAQxn.png)]. I have the following:

```
region = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['MatrixCUT'].faces.getByBoundingBox(100,0,0,100,100,100)
meshType=SHELL
numLayers=1
distanceBetweenLayers=0.0
initialOffset=100
mdb.models[name].parts[name].generateMeshByOffset(region, meshType,distanceBetweenLayers,numLayers,initialOffset,)
```

It seems that I have trouble with selecting the element faces. Any Advice?
[image]

Comment: You can make use of `findAt()` command.

Comment: Hello Satish, 

As far as I know, findAt () or getByBoundingBox () commands do not work with element face. The "generateMeshByOffset" function requires a region (variable) that express a sequence of element faces. When I macro record this move with the abaqus user interface I get the "getSequenceFromMask" method.